# How to dynamically pass ADLS gen2 folder/filename to Databricks Notebook in ADF or Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am using a Databricks Notebook Activity in ADF to transform files in ADLS gen2 folder. This folder is dynamic and a new folder is created on daily basis with daynumber. So I want my Databricks Notebook Activity to pickup foldername dynamically for each day to process files in that folder.

Can we do this ADF or within Databricks Notebook Activity?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to add dynamic content to the Notebook path?
I've made a test according to the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook#trigger-a-pipeline-run) and it works well:

1. First, I declare a parameter `name`.
   [image]
2. Switch to the Setting tab, I add the expression `@concat('/adftutorial/',string(dayOfMonth(utcnow())))` to the Notebook path text
   [image]
3. Then I run debug and enter `/path/filename` to the parameter
   [image]
4. It will read files in the dynamic path I specified before.
   [image]

In my case, the file doesn't exist so it pops up an error.